# Accessing external classes from Autofac Configuration

Tags: configuration, autofac

Been searching for an answer to a fairly simple question (I surmise).

Just starting out with Autofac and DI in general so I have a solution with 4 projects.
Console App looks like:

```
namespace ContainerPlugInPattern
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Option1: Fill container with known objects
                //var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                //// configuration - can be done programmatically or through configuration, 
                //// strongly typed with generics or more dynamically with Types, 
                //// can indicate whether created instances should be singleton or new instance per resolve
                //builder.RegisterType<Adapter1>().As<IInstrumentAdapter>();
                //builder.RegisterType<ExtraAdapter>().As<IInstrumentAdapter>();
                //builder.RegisterType<MessageHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>();
                //var container = builder.Build();

                // Option2: fill container from configured components
                //var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                //builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));
                //builder.RegisterType<MessageHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>();
                //var container = builder.Build();

                // Consumer code
                var adapters = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IInstrumentAdapter>>();
                foreach (var adapter in adapters)
                {
                    adapter.Configure("foo");
                    adapter.Connect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:{0}", ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Then a library (MyInterfaces.DLL and Namespace = MyInterfaces) that has an IInstrumentAdapter and IMessageHandler.

Then another library (DefaultAdapters.DLL and Namespace = ContainerPlugInPattern.DefaultAdapters) that has a class that implements IInstrumentAdapter

And finally the third library (ExtraAdapter.DLL and Namespace = ContainerPlugInPattern.ExtraAdapters) that has a class that also implements IInstrumentAdapter.

The main app has references to all the libraries and if I execute Option1 code at the top of the try block, I get console feedback that all objects have been created and run as expected.  The problem that I have here is that the main app has to have those references to work correctly (i.e. I cannot release these modules independently or extend with additional libraries over time).

What I really want is to load those components via the XML configuration and have those components exist in different assemblies and namespaces preferably without the need to reference them in the main app.  So my configuration file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="autofac" type="Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler, Autofac.Configuration" />
    </configSections>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>


    <autofac defaultAssembly="ContainerPlugInPattern">
        <components>
          <component 
            type="DefaultAdapters.Adapter1, ContainerPlugInPattern.DefaultAdapters"
            service="MyInterfaces.IInstrumentAdapter" />
          <component
            type="ExtraAdapter.ExtraAdapter, ContainerPlugInPattern.ExtraAdapter"
          service="MyInterfaces.IInstrumentAdapter" />
        </components>
    </autofac>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

When I try running the app with the configuration file I get the following exception:

Exception:The type 'DefaultAdapters.Adapter1, ContainerPlugInPattern.DefaultAdap
ters' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, M
yAssembly".

Hit enter to exit

Clearly I am not referencing the assembly/namespace correctly and tried several different permutations to get things to start up but to no avail.  The documentation was not very helpful so here I am.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultAssembly` should be the name of an assembly from which you want to register types. I see `MyInterfaces`, `DefaultAdapter`, and `ExtraAdapter` but you have `ContainerPlugInPattern` in there. Since you're registering types from two different assemblies, pick one of those.

The point of `defaultAssembly` is to make the XML shorter if you're registering a ton of types from one assembly. Every component `type` value should be the simple namespace-qualified name of a type *in the default assembly* or it needs to be *the full assembly-qualified type name* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Assembly qualified is `Namespace.Type, Assembly` like `ContainerPlugInPattern.DefaultAdapters.Adapter1, DefaultAdapters`. What you have seems to be a combination of types and namespaces in there. Switch to assembly qualified type names and you should be good to go. (If you switch and it still doesn't work, update your question with the new code so we can see what you tried.)

Comment: Thanks!  That was the push I needed, the  config now looks like this and everything is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the config now looks like

```
<autofac defaultAssembly="DefaultAdapters">
    <components>
      <component 
        type="ContainerPlugInPattern.DefaultAdapters.Adapter1, DefaultAdapters"
        service="MyInterfaces.IInstrumentAdapter, MyInterfaces" />
      <component
        type="ContainerPlugInPattern.ExtraAdapters.ExtraAdapter, ExtraAdapter"
      service="MyInterfaces.IInstrumentAdapter, MyInterfaces" />
    </components>
</autofac>
```